# Override importing module's built-in functions from imported module

Tags: python, python-import

I have an application where I would like to override certain functions when a condition occurs, for example:

condition_check.py:

```
Flag = True
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
import inspect
def MsgBox(msg):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, msg, 'MsgBox', 1)
def check():
    global print
    if Flag:
        def print(msg):
                MsgBox(msg)
    else:
        pass
```

main.py:

```
## works
from condition_check import *
MsgBox('this is msgbox')
print('this is a print')

## does not work
import condition_check
condition_check.MsgBox('this is msgbox')
print('this is a print')
```

I understand that the `condition_check.py` is overriding its own `print` instead of the `main.py`'s `print`. I believe **inspect** library could be used for this purpose but I am not able to lookup an example.

Comment: Don't conditionally override definitions ever. It may appear to be a clever trick, but it is certain to break things or at least confuse the next person (including you) that has to look at the code. Much better is `if Flag: MsgBox(message) else: print (message)`. The variable name `Flag` is also meaningless and if you are new to Python forget `global` exists, it will mostly get you into trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately I intend that main.py is unaware of certain functions it uses are being overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Python 3.  If you are, you need merely set an attribute of the built-in module.

```
import builtins
import ctypes

original = builtins.print
Flag = True

def MsgBox(msg):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, msg, 'MsgBox', 1)

def check():
    if Flag:
        builtins.print = MsgBox
    else:
        builtins.print = original
```

I will note, however, a couple things:

1. `Flag` is not a good name for two reasons: **1**, it isn't at all descriptive.  A flag merely means that it is `True` or `False`; it doesn't say anything about what it is for.  **2**, the official style guide for Python (PEP 8) recommends snake_case, not PascalCase for regular variables.  PascalCase should be used only for classes.
2. Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) are not recommended by PEP 8 because they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and automated tools.  (Almost an exact quotation from the section on [Imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).)
3. You don't need to override the `print` function.  A better way is to override `sys.stdout` to a stream that controls where it goes:

   ```
   import ctypes
   import sys

   def MsgBox(msg):
       ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, msg, 'MsgBox', 1)

   class Printer:
       def __init__(self, original, alternate, use_alternate):
           self.original = original
           self.alternate = alternate
           self.use_alternate = use_alternate

       def write(self, msg):
           if self.use_alternate:
               return self.alternate(msg)
           return self.original(msg)

   sys.stdout = printer = Printer(sys.stdout.write, MsgBox, True)
   ```

   Your flag is then `printer.use_alternate`.  Besides being much easier to control, this is also compatible with Python 2, even though the Python 2 `print` is a statement.  This does have the slight disadvantage of keeping the newline that `print` adds, but one can always use an `alternate` of something like `lambda msg: MsgBox(msg.strip())`

Comment: Thanks for expanding my comment. I am puzzled by the override of sys.stdout that you suggest, though. Once you've got a printer instance in hand, would not `printer.write(msg)` be clearer than the "action at a distance" override? Your suggestion gets 90% of the way there and then uses a global to ensure confusion. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @msw: Certainly `printer.write(msg)` is clearer, but the OP mentioned in a comment on the question that he doesn't want `main.py` to know that its messages are being redirected.

Comment: As for the global variable, I don't see that as a necessary problem.  Classes and functions are usually global.  The problem with global variables is when they leak into other namespaces.  With this, however, a properly-imported `condition_check` would use `condition_check.printer.use_alternate = False`, for example.  I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: "the OP mentioned in a comment on the question that he doesn't want main.py to know that its messages are being redirected." true that; unfortunately sometimes the new programmer does not know what good practice is, and it is my vanity that I can dissuade them from doing the Wrong Thing.

Comment: Thanks for all the supportive suggestions.